# Could Not Open Database In Android Studio

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I've created G class in-order to using database but in first steps I got this error :

```
   Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
```

Also in AndroidManifest.xml I added :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

This is my G class :

```
package com.example.n5110.database;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Environment;
import java.io.File;

public class G extends Application {
    public static Context context;
    public static SQLiteDatabase database;
    public static final String DIR_SDCARD = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    public static final String DIR_DATABASE = DIR_SDCARD + "/database-test/";

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        context = this.getApplicationContext();

        new File(DIR_DATABASE).mkdirs();
        database = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(DIR_DATABASE + "/database.sqlite", null);
    }
}
```

Does anyone have an idea??

Comment: If you are testing it on a device/emulator with API 24 or greater, you ned to use [Runtime Permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html).

Comment: @PrerakSola He would have gotten the Security Exception if that was the case. Sidenote: who calls a class G :D AFAIK the db may not open if there's no memory available. Check for that at least, so we can rule it out.

Comment: How should I check for the memory ? I'm Beginner !! @Vucko

Comment: well that can only be the issue on a real device, since you get virtual memory on your Emulator and it basically does not have anything that would occupy it. Check for memory in settings of your device.

Answer (score 0):

File dbFile = myContext.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME);
return dbFile.exists();

Hope it helps

Comment: it will actually help you locate your database file, get the path and then read it

Comment: new File(DIR_DATABASE).mkdirs();Path dbpath = myContext.getDatabasePath(dbname);
        database = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(dbpath + "/database.sqlite", null);
    }

Comment: i think if you are adding the permission and you still got the error of file not open, that means there is a possibility that the path is not correct